# Special Characters to HTML for API POST method in Javascript - Google Script

Tags: javascript, html, string, google-apps-script

I'm writing a script on Google Script to interact with the Airtable's API.
To ask the API to return a list of records based in a query, they provide the URL to send the post request. However, for the query part of the Url they ask to translate special characters to HTML.

Straight to my question: Is there any cleaner way to code this?
My first solution was to create a dictionary for each character, then run a "replace" method to substitute the special characters to the relative ones on the dictionary.
Any person with a bit more knowledge in Javascript than me? Remembering that I'm running this on Google Scripts.

```
function urlEncoder(toEncode) {

  var dictionary = {

    '(':'(',')':')','`':'%60','~':'~','!':'!','@':'%40','#':'%23','^':'%5E','$':'%24','%':'%25','&':'%26',
    '*':'*','-':'-','_':'_','=':'%3D','+':'%2B','[':'%5B',']':'%5D','{':'%7B','}':'%7D','\\':'%5C','|':'%7C',';':'%3B',':':':',
    '\'':'\'','\"':'\"',',':'%2C','<':'%3C','.':'.','>':'%3E','/':'%2F','?':'%3F',' ':'+',
    'à':'%C3%A0','À':'%C3%80','á':'%C3%A1','Á':'%C3%81','â':'%C3%A2','Â':'%C3%82','ä':'%C3%A4','Ä':'%C3%84','ã':'%C3%A3','Ã':'%C3%83',
    'è':'%C3%A8','È':'%C3%88','é':'%C3%A9','É':'%C3%89','ê':'%C3%AA','Ê':'%C3%8A','ë':'%C3%AB','Ë':'%C3%8B',
    'ì':'%C3%AC','Ì':'%C3%8C','í':'%C3%AD','Í':'%C3%8D',
    'ò':'%C3%B2','Ò':'%C3%92','ó':'%C3%B3','Ó':'%C3%93','ô':'%C3%B4','Ô':'%C3%94','ö':'%C3%B6','Ö':'%C3%96','õ':'%C3%B5','Õ':'%C3%95',
    'ù':'%C3%B9','Ù':'%C3%99','ú':'%C3%BA','Ú':'%C3%9A','û':'%C3%BB','Û':'%C3%9B','ü':'%C3%BC','Ü':'%C3%9C',
    'ç':'%C3%A7','Ç':'%C3%87','ñ':'%C3%B1','Ñ':'%C3%91'

  }

  var result = toEncode.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, m => dictionary[m])
  Logger.log('URL Encoder:'+toEncode+'>>'+result)
  return result
}
```

The string encoder provided by Airtable can be found here: https://codepen.io/airtable/full/rLKkYB

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to make your own function for that, there's already a function called `encodeURI` in javascript:

```
var url = "my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
var res = encodeURI(url);
// res = "my%20test.asp?name=st%C3%A5le&car=saab"
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It works great!
The only thing I'll have to modify, because of the API I'm working on, is to replace %20 to +. Everything else works fine.